# ¿Como establesco un valor minimo y maximo para un input tipo time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

estoy trabajando con angular y necesito estableces un valor mínimo y máximo en un input de tipo time.

```
<th class="col-md-6">
          <label class="col-form-label">Hora programada envio:</label>
          <input class="form-control d-block" type="time" id="horaProgramadaEnvio" name="horaProgramadaEnvio"
          
            required>
        </th>
```

intente con estos atributos [min]="17:00" y min="17:00", pero no tuve éxito.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo de como funciona el `min` y el `max` de manera correcta mi estimado, espero que te sirva!

```html
<form action="" name="formulario">
    <input type="time" name="hora" value="01:00:00" max="02:00:00" min="10:00:00" step="1">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Veras que por defecto aparece con el `01:00:00` por que es el valor mínimo especificado y si colocas un valor superior a `02:00:00` te dará una alerta por superar el máximo